# Zoom on mouseover in Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Is it possible to get the zoom functionality to happen when a user mouses over a slide, rather than double-taps? The double-tap method is great for touch, but for desktop it's not so intuitive, plus it plays havoc with other interactive elements (e.g. links, etc.)

Having the zoom by mouseover should allow a user to navigate around the zoomed slide image too in relation to the position of the mouse to the center of the slide. Moving the mouse to the top right would pan and zoom the slide image to the top right area, same with moving the mouse to any other corner or area within the zoom container.

If there was a switch to also enable inverted panning on the zoom that could be handy too (e.g. moving cursor to the top left would pan and zoom to bottom right of image).

Comment: did you try to do this or just a theory question ?

Comment: I tried it man but no result that why I posted here.

Comment: Can you share the code what you tried ? it would help us figure out the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

zoom in and zoom out of images using `Swiper` js library.

HTML

```html
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/zakiwarfel/128.jpg" class="media-object img-circle thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg" class="media-object img-circle thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Plain slide with text</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <!-- Override maxRatio parameter -->
                <div class="swiper-zoom-container" data-swiper-zoom="5">
                    <img src="path/to/image1.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
```

JS

```js
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: {
        maxRatio: 5,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
       }
    });
    
    var swiperSlide = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')
    for(var index = 0; index< swiperSlide.length; index++){
    swiperSlide[index].addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
        mySwiper.zoom.in();
    })
    
    swiperSlide[index].addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){
        mySwiper.zoom.out();
    })
    }
```

Comment: With your coding help, I resolved my issue. Thank u brother.

Comment: Glad it help. Thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I can confirm that this approach is still valid. But if you use Swiper as module and if you did not import all the modules, then you need to check if you already imported the zoom module. Otherwise, it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You can call following method on mouse over event.

> mySwiper.zoom.in

Here mySwiper is the instance of Swiper class.You can get information following [link](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#zoom).
Here is the example.

```js
window.Myswiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  zoom: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
img1.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
if(Myswiper.zoom.scale < 2)
  Myswiper.zoom.in()
})
img1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  Myswiper.zoom.out()
})
img2.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  if(Myswiper.zoom.scale < 2)
  Myswiper.zoom.in()
})
img2.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  Myswiper.zoom.out()
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
        <img id="img1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-hi.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
        <img id="img2" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/k/L/m/P/2/yellow-apple-md.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
  <!-- Add Navigation -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using **[react-id-swiper](https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper)** and also using **Swiper Vertical Thumbnails**

Here is the code example.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextState.gallerySwiper && nextState.thumbnailSwiper) {
    const { gallerySwiper, thumbnailSwiper } = nextState

    gallerySwiper.controller.control = thumbnailSwiper;
    thumbnailSwiper.controller.control = gallerySwiper;

    var swiperSlide = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-zoom-container')
    for(var index = 0; index<swiperSlide.length; index++){
      swiperSlide[index].addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
        gallerySwiper.zoom.in();
      })
      swiperSlide[index].addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){
        gallerySwiper.zoom.out();
      })
    }
  }
}
```